# How Can I Turn a Query String Parameter into a Cookie that then Sets an Attribute?

Tags: javascript, cookies, query-string, getelementsbyclassname

Been completely stumped by this but it should be easy. Basically I need a script that

1) Parses a URL for query string ?code=X190 (or any other code value).
2) If present creates a cookie with that attribute/value = so creates MyCookie with value X190 in this case.
3) As the User navigates the site, every page checks for MyCookie and if it finds it, it inserts X190 into the value attribute any form inputs of that page of class "xcode-field".

Right now I'm using `document.getElementById("xcode-field").setAttribute("value","X190");` for some dynamic insertions, but I need this to work on a class instead of an ID as there will be multiple forms per page in some cases.

UPDATE: Following the recommendation below I tried this using localStorage instead of cookies, got much further but still having issues saving the data: [HTML5 Local Storage item not being saved correclty](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/26181218/html5-local-storage-item-not-being-saved-correclty)

Comment: Have you considered HTML5 localStorage as an alternative to cookie?   Can you show any codes attempts you have made towards your solution?

Comment: Why should this happen at the client side? Why does your server at all have this field in the forms when the value is already known per the cookie?

Comment: I was actually not aware of localStorage and I'm researching it now, it could certainly work. As to the question of why this is client side, its all I could think of, no idea how to pass on this value side-wide in any other way. The forms are created by a proprietary cms and used on any sites/landing pages we chose to place them in. The xcode value would be gone from the url once once the the user navigates to a new page, so if they chose to fill the form there how would I populate it correctly without client-side storage?